# How to test functionality of function props in storybook?

Tags: reactjs, storybook

I have a parent component, `<AssetSelectorMenu>`, which is composed of two child components:

```
export const AssetSelectorMenu = (({ assets, sortByName }) => {

  return (
    <>
      <AssetSelectorHeader sortByName={sortByName} />
      {assets && assets.map((asset) => (
        <AssetSelectorRow key={asset} />
      ))}
    </>
  );
});
```

storybook for `AssetSelectorMenu`:

```
export const Default = () => (
  <AssetSelectorMenu sortByName={action("sortByName")} assets={assets} />
);
```

Inside the storybook for `AssetSelectorMenu`, I'd like to test that the function prop `sortByName` actually visually sorts the assets by name. At the moment, it only makes sure it the function gets called, but visually it's not sorting the assets. How can I do that?

Comment: Do you mean you want to add state to Storybook examples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use state in your Storybook examples so that your components are fully working based on interaction you need to use the `createElement` function from React.

Here is a simple example using a Checkbox component that has it's value managed by state which simulates using a state manager like Redux or Context etc.

```
import { Fragment, useState, createElement } from 'react'

<Preview>
  <Story name="Default">
    {createElement(() => {
      const [value, setValue] = useState(['Yes'])
      const onChange = (event, value) => {
        setValue(value)
      }
      return (
        <Checkbox
          name="checkbox"
          values={[
            { label: 'Yes', value: 'Yes' },
            { label: 'No', value: 'No' }
          ]}
          value={value}
          onChange={onChange}
        />
      )
    })}
  </Story>
</Preview>
```

Comment: Is it considered standard practice to test this way?

Comment: Well I manage a corporate design system and this is how we ensure that our devs, designers and product managers are able to interact with our components in a realistic way. When you say "test" however we also have unit tests using Jest/Enzyme that ensure the functionality is working as expected and in your case you would be able to unit test the sorting functionality to make sure it matches your expected output.